# What is maven clean repo building?

Tags: maven, build

I am new to maven and I heard the term "maven clean repo" building ? What is the meaning of this ? How it different from the normal maven building process ? Also I want to know about the maven repository and how it changes when we build the software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an exact term called "maven clean repo building" - but it is probably referring to doing a clean build by clearing out your entire LOCAL maven repository to ensure you have only the correct dependencies for your project.

All dependencies you need get downloaded into the repository which is at ${user.home}/.m2/repository by default. You can see this grows as the build runs and dependencies get downloaded into this folder.

The link 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html explains one way of purging this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the maven repo being used for the build by providing the following argument to the build command

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/sampleRepo
```

If relevant artifacts are not available in the pointed maven repo, it will download them from relevant repositories (maven central or repositories which are provided in the `pom.xml` file).

Hint;) Using a directory in `/tmp/` will be more good as `/tmp/` get automatically cleared in OS restart.